# SQL Non unique entries

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, having

I am trying to write a query that returns me the DateCode and ContainerName from two joined tables but only give me the records where DateCode is not unique (has multiple entries)
I feel like the SQL query I've written should do exactly that but I keep getting this error:

> Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference.

Perhaps I'm just too green to understand why this isn't working but here is my query:

```
SELECT LA.DateCode, C.ContainerName 
FROM CamstarSch.A_LotAttributes LA INNER JOIN 
     CamstarSch.Container C 
     ON C.ContainerId = LA.ContainerId
WHERE LA.DateCode IN (SELECT LA.DateCode 
                      FROM CamstarSch.A_LotAttributes 
                      GROUP BY LA.DateCode, C.ContainerName 
                      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
                    );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem with `subquery`, `DateCode` should be from subquery query :

```
WHERE LA.DateCode IN (SELECT AL.DateCode 
                      FROM CamstarSch.A_LotAttributes AS AL
                      GROUP BY AL.DateCode 
                      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
                    );
```

However, simple aggregation would also work :

```
SELECT LA.DateCode, C.ContainerName 
FROM CamstarSch.A_LotAttributes LA INNER JOIN 
     CamstarSch.Container C 
     ON C.ContainerId = LA.ContainerId
GROUP BY LA.DateCode, C.ContainerName 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Comment: Oooh that is very interesting, you have to change the naming of the table to be different than the outer query? That was the cause of the error?

Comment: Yes aliasing is important so that you know what "table" you are referencing.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty easy one, you were so close!

```
SELECT LA.DateCode, C.ContainerName, COUNT(*)
FROM CamstarSch.A_LotAttributes LA
INNER JOIN CamstarSch.Container C ON C.ContainerId = LA.ContainerId
GROUP BY LA.DateCode, C.ContainerName 
HAVING COUNT(*)>1
```

Comment: And of course you dont necessarily need to pull in the count - just did this as more of a demonstration

Comment: Hmmm, so I see what you're doing here and although it doesn't give me an error with this, I'm getting no results. I don't believe I can GROUP BY both DateCode and ContainerName. The same DateCode is listed many times with many different ContainerName 's.

Comment: My original inner query
```
SELECT LA.DateCode FROM CamstarSch.A_LotAttributes GROUP BY LA.DateCode HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```
returns around 1,300 results. So I should be getting more than that with the correct query

Comment: That inner query returns me all the DateCode values I need to display I just need to then display ALL of them

Comment: @MitchelBelmer Maybe I am misunderstanding your question then - you need non-unique values, right? Or any that apply to that container?

Comment: Im guessing my distinct count was the issue

Comment: I believe the distinct count was causing an issue there. Perhaps also the group by DateCode and ContianerName which was my fault. I added that earlier trying to troubleshoot and forgot to remove it.